# Actual Paypal Plus integration guide

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-plus

The last actual document that I found was dated in 2016. Can someone provide the most relevant document on the integration of PayPal Plus? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The [Paypal Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/directory/) lists two such guides:

1. [Integration guide — Germany](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf) (PDF V2.2)
2. [Integration guide — Mexico and Brazil](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-plus/mexico-brazil/paypal-plus-integration-guide-mexico-brazil/) (HTML)

Unfortunately, the german one is outdated. I have a newer one lying around here (I believe a PayPal emloyee sent it by mail) which has 07/19/2016 = Version 2.9 as last entry in its change history. I'm not sure that is the most recent one, though.

Comment: 07/19/2016 = [PDF V2.9.2](https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/emea/de/de/paypal-plus-center/PayPal_PLUS_integration_guide.pdf)

Comment: @kaluzki My document only states 2.9 in its change history. Does it have a subversion number somewhere else?

Comment: in file name -> "Microsoft Word - Integrating PayPal Plus Vers. 2.9.2.docx"